# Groups not showing in partial sandbox

Tags: sandbox, partial-sandbox

I created a partial sandbox and noticed that the groups in my production instance did not carry over.  Is this normal?

Comment: Chatter groups are not copied over on sandboxes. This is one of the most requested ideas on the ideas exchange. 

I recommend voting on this idea so that it can be implemented in future releases of Salesforce:
Chatter Groups and Profiles (but not data) in Sandbox Refreshes
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kzKMAAY

The only workaround that I can suggest for now is to manually re-create the chatter groups on the sandbox. Let me know if this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create/refresh a Sandbox chatter group do not copy or transfer.  So if you have to transfer chatter group data from one org to another check [here](https://patlatus.wordpress.com/2014/05/20/salesforce-transfer-chatter-group-data-from-one-organization-to-another/)

Kindly review below Idea links and vote for this feature.

[Chatter Groups should be replicated for Sandboxes](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kvr2AAA)

[Include Chatter Groups in Sandbox Refresh](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000Pa4AQAS)

Thanks,